# Carrusel de imagenes en Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, imagen, android-imageview, carrusel

Quiero hacer un carrusel de imagenes en un activity, para ello he creado el activity, el adapter y y un Fragment para las imagenes. En layout activity e item, pero no se ve nada, el cambio de activity lo hace pero nada más. ¿Qué tendría que modificar para que funcione?¿o alguna otra alternativa?

[![Así se ve][1]][1]

El código es el siguiente:

```
public class CarruselActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private ViewPager2 viewPager;

private int[] imagenes = {R.drawable.prenda1, R.drawable.prenda2, R.drawable.prenda3};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_carrusel);

    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new CarruselAdapter(this, imagenes));
}
```

}

```
public class CarruselAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CarruselAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private int[] imagenes;

public CarruselAdapter(Context context, int[] imagenes) {
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.imagenes = imagenes;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_carrusel, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.imagen.setImageResource(imagenes[position]);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return imagenes.length;
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView imagen;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imagen = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    }
}
```

}

```
public class ImagenFragment extends Fragment {
private int imagenResource;

public ImagenFragment(int imagenResource) {
    this.imagenResource = imagenResource;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_carrusel, container, false);
    ImageView imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    imageView.setImageResource(imagenResource);
    return view;
}
```

}

**item_carrusel.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
    

    android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        `android:layout_height="match_parent"`
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**activity_carrusel.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".CarruselActivity">

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

La idea es que al deslizar el dedo sobre la pantalla hacia la izquierda pase a la siguiente imagen, y al deslizar hacia la derecha pase a la imagen anterior, esto con la idea de que sea como un carrusel. Al menos quiero conseguir que las imagenes se muevan al deslizar
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkCbH.png